# Microsoft.Xades Open Source Dll Using PKCS11

Tags: c#, digital-signature, x509certificate, smartcard

XADES. I stuck at one point please help me out. iam using CSP to select the certificate from the store but i don't need an action from the user i only need to use pkcs11 wrapper to extract the private key from the smart-card [token] and use it for signature . iam using pkcs11 interop .net wrappr 
below is the code i use to extract the certificate from the store

```
  X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection collection = (X509Certificate2Collection) store.Certificates;
            X509Certificate2Collection fcollection =
                (X509Certificate2Collection) collection.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);
            X509Certificate2Collection scollection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(fcollection,
                "XAdES sample", "Choose a certificate", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);

            if (scollection != null && scollection.Count == 1)
            {
                cert = scollection[0];

                if (cert.HasPrivateKey == false)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("This certificate does not have a private key associated with it");
                    cert = null;
                }
            }

            store.Close();
```

and the code that i use to extract the private key from the smart card as below

```
      Pkcs11 pkcs11 = new Pkcs11(_pkcs11LibraryPath, false);
        //Get Info
        LibraryInfo libraryInfo = pkcs11.GetInfo();

        // Get list of available slots
        List<Slot> slots = pkcs11.GetSlotList(false);

        //Login to business slot 
        Slot paciSlot = slots[2];
        // Open RO session
        using (Session session = paciSlot.OpenSession(false))
        {
            //Sign and verify with certificate

            //Get Private Key
            List<ObjectAttribute> objectAttributes = new List<ObjectAttribute>();
            objectAttributes = new List<ObjectAttribute>();

            objectAttributes = new List<ObjectAttribute>();
            objectAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKO.CKO_PRIVATE_KEY));
            objectAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_KEY_TYPE, CKK.CKK_RSA));

            session.FindObjectsInit(objectAttributes);
            var oObjCollection = session.FindObjects(1);


            ObjectHandle oPrivKeyObjectHandle = new ObjectHandle();
            if (oObjCollection.Count > 0)
            {
                oPrivKeyObjectHandle = oObjCollection[0];
            }}
```

so how I use the private key from the smart card with Microsoft.xades dll .

edit to the question :-
below is the source code for signing using csp

```
       this.BuildDigestedReferences();
        AsymmetricAlgorithm signingKey = this.SigningKey;  //Certificate Private Key
        if (signingKey == null)
        {
            throw new CryptographicException("Cryptography_Xml_LoadKeyFailed");
        }
        if (this.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod == null)
        {
            if (!(signingKey is DSA))
            {
                if (!(signingKey is RSA))
                {
                    throw new CryptographicException("Cryptography_Xml_CreatedKeyFailed");
                }
                if (this.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod == null)
                {
                    this.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#dsa-sha1";
            }
        }
        SignatureDescription description = CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(this.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod) as SignatureDescription;
        if (description == null)
        {
            throw new CryptographicException("Cryptography_Xml_SignatureDescriptionNotCreated");
        }
        HashAlgorithm hash = new SHA1Managed();
        if (hash == null)
        {
            throw new CryptographicException("Cryptography_Xml_CreateHashAlgorithmFailed");
        }
        //this.GetC14NDigest(hash);
        this.GetC14NDigest(hash, "ds");

        this.m_signature.SignatureValue = description.CreateFormatter(signingKey).CreateSignature(hash);
```

and using pkcs11 library

```
        Pkcs11 pkcs11 = new Pkcs11(_pkcs11LibraryPath, false);
        //Get Info
        LibraryInfo libraryInfo = pkcs11.GetInfo();

        // Get list of available slots
        List<Slot> slots = pkcs11.GetSlotList(false);

        //Login to business slot 
        Slot paciSlot = slots[2];
        // Open RO session
        using (Session session = paciSlot.OpenSession(false))
        {
            //Sign and verify with certificate

            //Get Private Key
            var objectAttributes = new List<ObjectAttribute>
            {
                new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKO.CKO_PRIVATE_KEY),
                new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_KEY_TYPE, CKK.CKK_RSA)
            };

            session.FindObjectsInit(objectAttributes);
            var oObjCollection = session.FindObjects(1);


            ObjectHandle oPrivKeyObjectHandle = new ObjectHandle();
            if (oObjCollection.Count > 0)
            {

                oPrivKeyObjectHandle = oObjCollection[0];

            }

            // Specify signing mechanism
            Mechanism mechanism = new Mechanism(CKM.CKM_SHA1_RSA_PKCS);

            byte[] signature = session.Sign(mechanism, oPrivKeyObjectHandle, hashedata);
```

the signature using csp is different than using pkcs11 how ever iam using the same private key .

thank you

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extract private key from the smart card, otherwise you could copy/duplicate the smart card defeating its primary purpose(to be unique and secure)

-You can use [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/)  which has a lot of useful Crypto APIs

Comment: thank you for your replay hampidampi .is there a way to cast the private key to asymmetric algorithm key as use in below code            RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter formatter
                    = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(this.SigningKey);
            formatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA1");
            this.m_signature.SignatureValue = formatter.CreateSignature(hash);

Comment: @MohamedElbadrawy It is not possible to cast private key handle acquired via PKCS#11 to AsymmetricAlgorithm class but it should be possible to implement your own class inherited from AsymmetricAlgorithm.

Comment: thank you for your replay jariq , just wondering to solve the issue from other way , when i sign hashed value like 'hello world ' with the below code ' description.CreateFormatter(signingKey).CreateSignature(hash);' it giveing me different signature than using pkcs11 , from my information the y should be the same .

Comment: @MohamedElbadrawy There are many digital signature formats available and to really answer your question I would need to see a bigger chunk of the source code (not just the method name).

Comment: Jariq i have included the code for signing in the question .